# Does GAE support load-time weaving?

Tags: google-app-engine, aspectj

I tried configuring spring using

```
<context:load-time-weaver weaver-class=
    "org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
```

but I get this exception trying to run locally using GAE:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ClassLoader [com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader] 
does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
```

Are there any LTW instrumenting classes available that are supported by GAE?

Thank you!
Chris

Comment: Using org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver instead of ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver will not throw any exceptions. Haven't yet successfully done LTW in GAE yet though.